# Date format set in Excel is ignored when using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm using the Microsoft Office C# library (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`) to write some values to an existing excel file.

In Excel I've already formatted some cells in the file to be interpreted as a date, as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, the cell is set to a `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

However, when I then wrote the value using the interop library, like this:

```
cell.Value2 = "20/06/2019"
```

I noticed that it wasn't working: when I opened the final file in Excel the cell was being interpreted as plain text, instead of a date.

So I did some debugging, and it turns out that the format I set for the cell is completely ignored, and that the interop library is using the American format, as you can see by inspecting the `NumberFormat` property of the cell with the visual studio debugger:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Why is the American date format being forced?
Some additional info:

- My OS locale (italian) uses the `dd/MM/yyyy` format by default
- I did not change the locale of my c# app in any way
- My copy of Excel is set to italian, which should use the `dd/MM/yyyy` format by default as well. I checked under Options -> Language, and I can confirm this.

EDIT: and interesting thing I found: if I double-click on a cell and then click away from it, it "magically" fixes the formatting.... why? And can I simulate a double click on the cell using Excel Interop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates in Excel are stored as double representing OLE Automation date.
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8)

In your case, you are setting a string value. 
A proper way to set a date in Excel is following:

```
cell.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
cell.Value = new DateTime(2019, 6, 20).ToOADate();
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically the Number Format is only used to display the data, but not to interpret it, correct?

Comment: "The number format does not affect the cell value that Excel uses to perform calculations. The actual value is displayed in the formula bar" You can find some more info here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB